# Why does server mode of CLR garbage collector occupies more memory than workstation mode?

Tags: garbage-collection, clr

I have the below test that I run in workstation mode and server mode for CLR garbage collector. At the end in server mode I end up with 520 MB private bytes where as in workstation mode, I only end up with 50 MB. Here's my output from windbg:

```
!eeheap
...
...
GC Heap Size:            Size: 0x65ccac8 (106744520) bytes.


!address -summary
...
...
--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_FREE                                 53     7ffb`ae203000 ( 127.983 Tb)           99.99%
MEM_RESERVE                              94        4`31617000 (  16.772 Gb)  97.06%    0.01%
MEM_COMMIT
```

336        0`207d6000 ( 519.836 Mb)   2.94%    0.00%

What is the thing causes that big difference despite the fact that at the end of the execution I force full GC?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class Program
{
    static int N = 25 * 1000 * 1000;  // Execute allocations in a loop 25 million times
    static int Clear = 1000 * 1000;   // Clear list after every 1 million allocations to give GC 25 chances to clear things up

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // do some warmup
        AllocateRefContainer();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.Collect();

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        AllocateRefContainer();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("RefContainer Allocation {0:F2}s, {1:N0} Allocs/s", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, N / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

        GC.Collect();
        GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("PooledRefContainer Allocation {0:F2}s, {1:N0} Allocs/s", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, N / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Private Bytes: {0:N0} MB", Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64 / (1024 * 1024));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class ReferenceContainer // Class with one object reference
    {
        public ReferenceContainer Obj;
    }

    static List<ReferenceContainer> RContainer = new List<ReferenceContainer>();
    static void AllocateRefContainer()
    {
        var container = RContainer;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            container.Add(new ReferenceContainer());
            Calculate();
            if (i % Clear == 0)
            {
                container.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    // Simulate some CPU only calculation
    static void Calculate()
    {
        long lret = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            lret++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: [Just RTFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#workstation_and_server_garbage_collection).

Comment: I read it already. I fail to see any explanation with regards to above behaviour

Comment: You can't really miss "a heap for every cpu" and "larger size segments".

Comment: MEM_COMMIT                              336        0`207d6000 ( 519.836 Mb)   2.94%    0.00%

GC Heap Size:            Size: 0x65ccac8 (106744520) bytes.
Then how will you explain above. All heaps are only 106 MB where as COMMITTED size is 520

Answer (score 0):

Server mode runs 1 GC thread per logical processor core. This thread is allocated its own working set. There's therefore about 8x the overhead if you have 8 cores. Also the GC is non-deterministic, so you cannot reliably assess the memory usage since the reported bytes are those *reserved* for the app, not those necessarily *used*. Server GC is much more aggressive and may reserve more bytes.

[See this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#workstation_and_server_garbage_collection) for more information.